# Sitecore - not able to assign roles to new user

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

In my sitecore content authoring, i'm trying to create new user and to assign the roles. But the roles are not being added to the user. Not sure what is going wrong. I have done this before, in same authoring server and i succeeded.

Below are the screen shots.

1. In Ribbion -> Usermanager -> New : Below screen appeared and filled these details.

[image]

2. Clicked on Edit Roles and added the roles.

[image]

3. Clicked on Ok. I don't see roles being added to the list.

[image]

Here are the few information : 
1. I'm using sitecore 6.6
2. Tried in latest chrome and Mozilla browser.

Comment: This looks familiar, are you adding the roles by clicking the "Add" button? Also do you see any messages in the Console of the browser or in the logs?

Comment: @AdrianIorgu I'm double clicking the roles and adding. Also i tried by Add button. the result is same.  Below logs i can see in the console log.

Comment: 4Sitecore.js:143 SessionTimeout not found in settings scForm.Settings
InternetExplorer.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: object.attachEvent is not a function
n.

Comment: Maybe is  this bug ?  https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/826753

Comment: @SitecoreClimber is correct. Sitecore 6 is incompatible with Chrome versions of 37 or higher. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue . Here is the reference into Sitecore Knowledge Base site :

http://kb.sitecore.net/articles/826753